# Run multiple project meanio on a server

Tags: mean-stack, mean.io

I have project mean.io on a server. I want to run them simultaneously. I don't know how do make it?

Please help me,

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

## Run on separate ports

Go to the conf file of the project and change the port from 3000 to something else. Then you can run multiple projects and port numbers wont conflict.